# How do I format and structure data extracted from .msg files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working on reading and formatting a large set of rain gauge data from historical records stored in .msg files. These files contain untabulated text separated by spaces. However, I am facing an issue when running my script as the columns do not populate with data. Instead, only the dates are displayed with empty rows.

My objective is to pivot this data using pandas and create a DF where each row represents a Rain Gauge. The column headers will consist of timestamps paired with either 'PastHour' or 'ThisEvent'. Each cell within the DF will contain the corresponding rainfall value.

This is what I desired for both the "past hour" and "This event"

```
Gauge   07/02/2020 22:39:40 07/02/2020 23:39:40 07/02/2020 03:08:12 07/02/2020 04:08:12
Pereira         .90              .20                0
Puebla          .50               0                 0
CI              .63               .50               0
Tokito          0                 0                 0
CO             0                  0                 .05
KP              0                 0                 0
DSS             0                 0                 0
PL              0                 0                 0
TSM             0                 0                 0
PKP             0                 0                 0
RP              0                 0                 0
HP              0                 0                 0
GG              0                 0                 0
BB              0                 0                 0
```

This is my code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from extract_msg import Message

def parse_msg_file(filepath):
    msg = Message(filepath)
    body_lines = msg.body.split('\n')

    # Find and parse date and time
    date_str = None
    for line in body_lines:
        if line.startswith('Rain Report at '):
            date_str = line.replace('Rain Report at ', '')
            break

    if date_str is None:
        print(f"Can't find date string in file {filepath}")
        return []

    try:
        date = pd.to_datetime(date_str)
        date_hour = date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Can't parse date string '{date_str}' in file {filepath}")
        return []

    # Parse rain data
    data = []
    rain_data_line_found = False
    for line in body_lines:
        if line.startswith('Rain    Past    This'):
            rain_data_line_found = True
            continue

        if rain_data_line_found:
            parts = line.split()
            if len(parts) == 3:
                gauge, past_hour, this_event = parts
                try:
                    past_hour = float(past_hour)
                except ValueError:  # Handle 'N/A' and other non-floats
                    past_hour = pd.NA
                try:
                    this_event = float(this_event)
                except ValueError:  # Handle 'N/A' and other non-floats
                    this_event = pd.NA
                data.append((gauge, date_hour, past_hour, this_event))
            else:
                break  # End of the rain data section

    return data

# Use a thread pool executor to read multiple files at the same time
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    folder_path = 'C:\\Users\\'  # Update this path
    filepaths = [os.path.join(folder_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(folder_path) if filename.endswith('.msg')]

    all_data = []
    for data in executor.map(parse_msg_file, filepaths):
        all_data.extend(data)

# Convert to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=['Gauge', 'DateHour', 'Past Hour', 'This Event'])

# Pivot DataFrame
df_past_hour = df.pivot(index='Gauge', columns='DateHour', values='Past Hour')
df_this_event = df.pivot(index='Gauge', columns='DateHour', values='This Event')

# Save DataFrame to an Excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\rain_data4.xlsx') as writer:
    df_past_hour.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Past Hour')
    df_this_event.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='This Event')
```

How all .msg look like

```
________________________________________
From: Random <user@gmail.com>
Sent: Sunday, July 2, 2020 9:39:41 PM (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
To: Gauge-Rain Notification
Subject: Rain Report at 7/2/2020 9:39:40 PM

Rain Report at 7/2/2020 9:39:40 PM

Rain    Past    This
Gauge   Hour    Event**

Pereira    0.00          0.00
Puebla    0.30          0.49
CI       0.00          0.11
Tokito     0.01          0.18
CO       0.00          0.04
KP          N/A          N/A
DSS      0.00           0.00
PL       0.00          0.00
TSM      0.00          0.00
PKP      0.00          0.01
RP      1.00          1.42
HP      0.00          0.00
GG      0.20          0.45
BB      0.00          0.28

Since the onset of this particular rain event. (May include rainfall before midnight) **Each rain gauge has separate rain events.

Flow Report at 7/2/2020 9:39:40 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

When `line` is empty `len` from `parts = line.split()` is not equal to 3.

The instruction after `if len(parts) == 3:` is not executed, because of the blank line between:

```
Gauge   Hour    Event**

Pereira    0.00          0.00
```

Instead is executed the else statement, in this case `break`, which breaks out of the `for line in body_lines:` loop and no data is read before even the pandas operations have started.

To overcome this issue change `if rain_data_line_found:` to `if line and rain_data_line_found:`